# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting while printing with %

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a beginner in Python2.7, I am facing an issue while trying to execute below code. The first error pops up on line 3 (print). I get the error-> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting. Please help.
Below is my code snippet:

```
inputhours= int(raw_input('Enter the hours: '))

inputrate= int(raw_input('Enter the rate: '))

print('Hours is: '% inputhours)

print('Rate is: '% inputrate)

if (inputhours >40) :

    pay= int((40*10)+(inputhours - 40)*(inputrate * 1.5))

    print ('Pay is:'% pay)

else:

    pay= int(inputhours * inputrate)

    print ('Pay is:'% pay)

quit()
```

Spaces in above program are for your readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the tokens to replace in your initial strings. Your print statements should look like this:

```
print('Hours is: %d' % inputhours)
print('Rate is: %d' % inputrate)
```

or you can use the newer [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method of the string class like this:

```
print('Hours is: {:d}'.format(inputhours))
print('Rate is: {:d}'.format(inputrate))
```

Comment: @A.Viz hook a brother up with an upvote if it worked!